# How to serve a console application over SSH

Tags: ssh, shell

How is it usually solved when there is an SSH server, and when the user logs in, there is a cli application, (eg. a simple menu) that you can't exit / start a new bash shell.

Is it as simple as changing the shell for the given user?

Comment: My answer assumes standard Linux-like setup. Is this assumption right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `ForceCommand` option in [`sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ForceCommand):

> `ForceCommand`
>   Forces the execution of the command specified by `ForceCommand`, ignoring any command supplied by the client and `~/.ssh/rc` if present. The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the `-c` option. This applies to shell, command, or subsystem execution. It is most useful inside a Match block. The command originally supplied by the client is available in the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable. […] The default is none.

It says "the command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the `-c` option", so you need to `exec` another tool, not just run it:

```
ForceCommand exec top
```

This way the user's login shell will be replaced by `top` right away, the shell will be no more. Exiting the tool will terminate the connection.

Notes:

- This affects logging in via SSH only, the user can still log in locally and get the shell (if this method is not deliberately disabled by other means). You're talking about SSH access, not general access, so I assume this is what you want.
- Your question starts with "How is it usually solved …". I have no idea if this is how it is *usually* solved, all I know is this is a *possible* way.
- To affect a single user you need a conditional block, e.g.:

  ```
  Match User spectator
    ForceCommand exec top
  ```
- Some tools allow users to run arbitrary commands and get a shell anyway. (I'm not even sure if `top` is safe in this matter, treat it as an example).